# How do i get data-attribute of all siblings and this?

Tags: jquery

I have this markup:

```
<div class="photoList">
  <img src="http://example.com/img1.jpg" data-zoom-url="http://example.com/img1.jpg">
  <img src="http://example.com/img1.jpg" data-zoom-url="http://example.com/img1.jpg">
</div>
```

I want to have an array with all the values in data-zoom url. this is as close as I get:

```
console.log($j(this).parent().children().attr('data-zoom-url'))
```

The main problem is that parent-child is kind of not nice and that the thing i get back isn't an array and contains all sorts of stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.map`

```
var dataValues = $j(this).parent().children().map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-zoom-url')
}).get();
```